# valueForKeyPath: @"@max.self" returning nil for iOS 9.3.5?

Tags: ios, objective-c, iphone, ios9.3

I am trying to find out maximum value from an array using `@"@max.self"` but it is returning nil when I try to run it on iOS 9.3.5 device, for the Higher version it works properly and returns the proper value.

```
NSNumber *maxOfBarGraphValues = [arrayOfBarGraphValues valueForKeyPath:@"@max.self"];

 NSLog(@"%@",[[arrayOfBarGraphValues valueForKeyPath: @"@max.self"]floatValue] );
```

Below I am attaching output for the `NSLog` statement and value of `arrayOfBarGraphValues` from the console.

```
Printing description of self->arrayOfBarGraphValues: <__NSArrayM 0x16e1ffc0>
( 
5,
4,
7,
7,
6,
6,
7,
7,
7,
7,
7,
7,
7 
)

(lldb) po maxOfBarGraphValues  
nil
```

Comment: Can you show me the line which you create `arrayOfBarGraphValues`?

Comment: @property (nonatomic, weak) NSArray *arrayOfBarGraphValues;

Comment: I mean the line you assign value for `arrayOfBarGraphValues` @Karan Bhatia

Comment: sorry I was trying to post the code!

Comment: Have no idea with your comment.

Comment: what is the type of the items in your `arrayOfBarGraphValues`?

Comment: it is an NSMutableArray

Comment: @holex come down guy ;) . @KaranBhatia which type of numbers in your array? `NSNumber`, `NSString` or something else.

Comment: NSNumber @trungduc

Comment: but when I am trying to print "[arrayOfBarGraphValues valueForKeyPath:@"@max.self"]" it has a value.

Comment: @KaranBhatia what is this value?

Answer (score 0):

Follow this code hope will helpful to you.

```
NSArray *  arrayOfBarGraphValues = @[@5, @4, @7 ,@7 , @6, @6  ,@7  ,@7  ,@7  ,@7  ,@7  ,@7  ,@7 ];
int maxOfBarGraphValues = [[arrayOfBarGraphValues valueForKeyPath: @"@max.self"] intValue];
NSLog(@" MaximumValue Of BarGraph  = %d", maxOfBarGraphValues);

Output:- // Maximum = 7
```